# Change all numbers in a block of text all at once

Tags: vim, substitution

I have a file (pac file) that contains IP addresses for a certain corporation and want to obscure out every IP address within it. One idea I had was to add 1 to every digit in the file and mod the resulting number with 256, so that it still remains a valid IP.

For e.g 129 will become `2310 % 256 = 6`

Is there a quick way to apply such a change using vim? It sounds ambitious, but I thought I'd still ask. Here is an example of one block from the file.

```
if (

    isInNet(ip, "111.222.123.234", "255.255.255.224")  ||

    isInNet(ip, "166.19.10.14", "255.255.255.192") ||


)

{return "DIRECT";}
```

Comment: I added an answer to get you started but I don't know where you are getting 129 nor 2310 from

Comment: Thanks @AndyRay I gave 129 as a simple example. It is not an IP octet in the snippet I posted. Let me try out your solution.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to replace the IPs with totally random ones instead of applying a weak reversible encryption?

Comment: @DaanBakker yes I agree - my algorithm for replacing IPs is weak. I wanted to accomplish this using vim - do you have a recipe for randomly replacing digits in an ip?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a single search/replace command that does it all:

```
:s/\d\+/\=substitute(tr(submatch(0), '0123456789', '1234567890'), '0', '10', 'g') % 256/g
```

(Add your own range, e.g. by selecting a block in visual mode and doing `:'<,'>s` (or `:%s` for the whole file)).

- We start by matching all numbers (i.e. sequences of digits: `\d\+`).
- For each of those we rotate digits: `0` becomes `1`, `1` becomes `2`, ..., `9` becomes `0` (done using `tr()`).
- But `9` was supposed to become `10`, not `0`, so we apply another substitution that turns all `0` into `10` (done using `substitute()`).
- The final result is then taken modulo 256 (`% 256`).

Comment: Ähm, was submatch(0) +1 too easy?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt How would `+ 1` turn `129` into `2310`?

Comment: @melpomene I must have missed something. I thought the whole point was to add 1 to the ip address

Comment: @melpomene BTW: This should work: `:s/\d/\=submatch(0)+1/g` note, that i left out the + quantifier, which means, every digit will be incremented by one.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Vim's little-known "expression register" `:h CTRL-R_=`

In insert mode, if you type <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> it opens a prompt which you can do math at.

So for this line:

```
isInNet(ip, "111.222.123.234", "255.255.255.224")  ||
```

This pattern would do it (with cursor on the first `1`)

- <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> change inside lowercase word
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> Open the expression register
- <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> <kbd>"</kbd> Paste the contents of the quote register, which is what you just cut
- Add `% 256` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You should be able to macroize this, and add `+1` or parenthesis where you need.

Answer (score 1):

To get random IPs I recommend you use an external program. E.g. bash or python:

```
:%s/\d\+/\=system('bash -c "echo -ne $(( ( RANDOM % 256 ) ))"')/
:%s/\d\+/\=system('python -c "import random,sys;sys.stdout.write(str(random.randint(0,255)))"')/
```

Here is a more specific longer oneliner that only matches ipv4 addresses and generates entire IPs:

```
:%s/\v(\d{1,3})(\.\d{1,3}){3}/\=system('python -c "import random,sys;sys.stdout.write(''.''.join(str(random.randint(0,255)) for i in range(4)))"')/
```